# Angular: manually instantiate class with dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, production

I am using Angular 10.0 and I have a problem with --prod compiling.
I need to instantiate classes manually and need to support dependency injection.
The following code works fine during development to instantiate my classes:

```js
public instantiateWithDi(parentInjector: Injector, myClass: any): any {
  const reflector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([], parentInjector);
  const newInstance = reflector.resolveAndInstantiate(myClass);
  return newInstance;
}
```

When I build my project with --prod (or --optimization=true), then I get the following error at runtime:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'e'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'e' is decorated with Injectable.
```

Decorating the constructor parameters of the classes with @Inject did not work either. Using injection tokens does not help as well.
The classes are already decorated with @Injectable() and in the "providers" array of their respective angular module.

I know, the ReflectiveInjector is deprecated, but simply using the get method of the injector does not work either, because it seems to cache the classes once created and does not re-instantiate them each time I call my "instantiateWithDi" method.

**Example usage**

I've created a small demo at stackbliz for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plugin-mechanism?file=src/app/plugin-execution.service.ts

Basically the magic happens here (plugin-execution.service.ts):

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PluginExecutionService {

  public static readonly eventListeners = [];

  constructor(private injector: Injector){}

  private instantiateWithDi(parentInjector: Injector, myClass: any): any {
    const reflector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([], parentInjector);
    const newInstance = reflector.resolveAndInstantiate(myClass);
    return newInstance;
  }

  public onApplicationEvent(event: ApplicationEvent){
    const injector = Injector.create({
      parent: this.injector,
      providers: [{
        provide: ApplicationEvent,
        useValue: event
      }]
    });

    PluginExecutionService
        .eventListeners
        .forEach(cls => this.instantiateWithDi(injector, cls));
  }
}
```

This allows developers to create a class and push their class into a eventListener array. It gets executed every time, an application event occurs.

See the example "plugin" some.plugin.ts in the stackblitz example.

The real usecase is of course much more complex and involves custom decorators and stuff, but that would be quite an overkill for a demo.

You see the result in the console. The "plugins" work fine as intended. But when i build it using --prod, the app does not work any longer...

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Manuel

Comment: Please show an example of usage.

Comment: Just added a stackblitz to my question.

Comment: You can get this to work with the non-deprecated standard injector, without having the instance cached: [see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plugin-mechanism-weq4wk?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/plugin-execution.service.ts).

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you very much!one quick note: i've tried this before and it didnt work. because i've seen on your stackblitz that it works, i've done some more investigation on why it does not work on my side.
i dont know why, but i need to create two separate injectors. one parent injector (providing the ApplicationEvent) and another "child" injector, providing the plugin classes. the child injector must inherit the parent injector. after that, i am able to instantiate the classes using the child injector. why ever...
could you please add your comment as an answer so i can mark it?

Comment: Glad I could help. Something that makes debugging such an issue faster is running `ng-serve` with the production configuration. I don't know why that you would need multiple injector hierarchies, there could be many reasons. Anyway, I'll add an answer after I get some sleep.

Comment: Sleep tight, my friend ;)